# Position the list of cards correctly below the web-page elements, clipping issue

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following web page which basically has a few div elements placed one after the other and are centered in the view of a mobile or a desktop and have appropriate media queries to alter the text size.

I recently got a requirement to add a list of horizontally scrolling cards below the current existing page and i tried doing so like follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">-->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
    html {
        height: 100%
    }

    #mainbody {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #applink a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: #9FA8DA;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border-color: white;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    }

    .valign-center {
        display: inline-flex;
        vertical-align: middle;
        align-items: center;
    }

    /* This is the new content added to style the cards*/

    .card-block {
        min-height: 150px;
        min-width: 250px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    /*new content end*/

    body {
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #3f51b5;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='260' height='260' viewBox='0 0 260 260'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23abeae8' fill-opacity='0.17'%3E%3Cpath d='M24.37 16c.2.65.39 1.32.54 2H21.17l1.17 2.34.45.9-.24.11V28a5 5 0 0 1-2.23 8.94l-.02.06a8 8 0 0 1-7.75 6h-20a8 8 0 0 1-7.74-6l-.02-.06A5 5 0 0 1-17.45 28v-6.76l-.79-1.58-.44-.9.9-.44.63-.32H-20a23.01 23.01 0 0 1 44.37-2zm-36.82 2a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-3.1 1.56.89 1.79 1.31-.66a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .86.02l2.88-1.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.43 0l2.88 1.27a1 1 0 0 0 .85-.02l3.1-1.55-.89-1.79-1.42.71a3 3 0 0 1-2.56.06l-2.77-1.23a1 1 0 0 0-.4-.09h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.4.09l-2.78 1.23a3 3 0 0 1-2.56-.06l-2.3-1.15a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1L.9 19.22a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01zm0-2h-4.9a21.01 21.01 0 0 1 39.61 0h-2.09l-.06-.13-.26.13h-32.31zm30.35 7.68l1.36-.68h1.3v2h-36v-1.15l.34-.17 1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0L2.26 23h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.56.06l1.67-.74h3.23l1.67.74a3 3 0 0 0 2.56-.06zM-13.82 27l16.37 4.91L18.93 27h-32.75zm-.63 2h.34l16.66 5 16.67-5h.33a3 3 0 1 1 0 6h-34a3 3 0 1 1 0-6zm1.35 8a6 6 0 0 0 5.65 4h20a6 6 0 0 0 5.66-4H-13.1z'/%3E%3Cpath id='path6_fill-copy' d='M284.37 16c.2.65.39 1.32.54 2H281.17l1.17 2.34.45.9-.24.11V28a5 5 0 0 1-2.23 8.94l-.02.06a8 8 0 0 1-7.75 6h-20a8 8 0 0 1-7.74-6l-.02-.06a5 5 0 0 1-2.24-8.94v-6.76l-.79-1.58-.44-.9.9-.44.63-.32H240a23.01 23.01 0 0 1 44.37-2zm-36.82 2a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-3.1 1.56.89 1.79 1.31-.66a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .86.02l2.88-1.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.43 0l2.88 1.27a1 1 0 0 0 .85-.02l3.1-1.55-.89-1.79-1.42.71a3 3 0 0 1-2.56.06l-2.77-1.23a1 1 0 0 0-.4-.09h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.4.09l-2.78 1.23a3 3 0 0 1-2.56-.06l-2.3-1.15a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01zm0-2h-4.9a21.01 21.01 0 0 1 39.61 0h-2.09l-.06-.13-.26.13h-32.31zm30.35 7.68l1.36-.68h1.3v2h-36v-1.15l.34-.17 1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.56.06l1.67-.74h3.23l1.67.74a3 3 0 0 0 2.56-.06zM246.18 27l16.37 4.91L278.93 27h-32.75zm-.63 2h.34l16.66 5 16.67-5h.33a3 3 0 1 1 0 6h-34a3 3 0 1 1 0-6zm1.35 8a6 6 0 0 0 5.65 4h20a6 6 0 0 0 5.66-4H246.9z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M159.5 21.02A9 9 0 0 0 151 15h-42a9 9 0 0 0-8.5 6.02 6 6 0 0 0 .02 11.96A8.99 8.99 0 0 0 109 45h42a9 9 0 0 0 8.48-12.02 6 6 0 0 0 .02-11.96zM151 17h-42a7 7 0 0 0-6.33 4h54.66a7 7 0 0 0-6.33-4zm-9.34 26a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-4.34a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-4.34a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-7a7 7 0 1 1 0-14h42a7 7 0 1 1 0 14h-9.34zM109 27a9 9 0 0 0-7.48 4H101a4 4 0 1 1 0-8h58a4 4 0 0 1 0 8h-.52a9 9 0 0 0-7.48-4h-42z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M39 115a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm6-8a6 6 0 1 1-12 0 6 6 0 0 1 12 0zm-3-29v-2h8v-6H40a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v10H22l-1.33 4-.67 2h2.19L26 130h26l3.81-40H58l-.67-2L56 84H42v-6zm-4-4v10h2V74h8v-2h-8a2 2 0 0 0-2 2zm2 12h14.56l.67 2H22.77l.67-2H40zm13.8 4H24.2l3.62 38h22.36l3.62-38z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M129 92h-6v4h-6v4h-6v14h-3l.24 2 3.76 32h36l3.76-32 .24-2h-3v-14h-6v-4h-6v-4h-8zm18 22v-12h-4v4h3v8h1zm-3 0v-6h-4v6h4zm-6 6v-16h-4v19.17c1.6-.7 2.97-1.8 4-3.17zm-6 3.8V100h-4v23.8a10.04 10.04 0 0 0 4 0zm-6-.63V104h-4v16a10.04 10.04 0 0 0 4 3.17zm-6-9.17v-6h-4v6h4zm-6 0v-8h3v-4h-4v12h1zm27-12v-4h-4v4h3v4h1v-4zm-6 0v-8h-4v4h3v4h1zm-6-4v-4h-4v8h1v-4h3zm-6 4v-4h-4v8h1v-4h3zm7 24a12 12 0 0 0 11.83-10h7.92l-3.53 30h-32.44l-3.53-30h7.92A12 12 0 0 0 130 126z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M212 86v2h-4v-2h4zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-20 0v.1a5 5 0 0 0-.56 9.65l.06.25 1.12 4.48a2 2 0 0 0 1.94 1.52h.01l7.02 24.55a2 2 0 0 0 1.92 1.45h4.98a2 2 0 0 0 1.92-1.45l7.02-24.55a2 2 0 0 0 1.95-1.52L224.5 96l.06-.25a5 5 0 0 0-.56-9.65V86a14 14 0 0 0-28 0zm4 0h6v2h-9a3 3 0 1 0 0 6H223a3 3 0 1 0 0-6H220v-2h2a12 12 0 1 0-24 0h2zm-1.44 14l-1-4h24.88l-1 4h-22.88zm8.95 26l-6.86-24h18.7l-6.86 24h-4.98zM150 242a22 22 0 1 0 0-44 22 22 0 0 0 0 44zm24-22a24 24 0 1 1-48 0 24 24 0 0 1 48 0zm-28.38 17.73l2.04-.87a6 6 0 0 1 4.68 0l2.04.87a2 2 0 0 0 2.5-.82l1.14-1.9a6 6 0 0 1 3.79-2.75l2.15-.5a2 2 0 0 0 1.54-2.12l-.19-2.2a6 6 0 0 1 1.45-4.46l1.45-1.67a2 2 0 0 0 0-2.62l-1.45-1.67a6 6 0 0 1-1.45-4.46l.2-2.2a2 2 0 0 0-1.55-2.13l-2.15-.5a6 6 0 0 1-3.8-2.75l-1.13-1.9a2 2 0 0 0-2.5-.8l-2.04.86a6 6 0 0 1-4.68 0l-2.04-.87a2 2 0 0 0-2.5.82l-1.14 1.9a6 6 0 0 1-3.79 2.75l-2.15.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.54 2.12l.19 2.2a6 6 0 0 1-1.45 4.46l-1.45 1.67a2 2 0 0 0 0 2.62l1.45 1.67a6 6 0 0 1 1.45 4.46l-.2 2.2a2 2 0 0 0 1.55 2.13l2.15.5a6 6 0 0 1 3.8 2.75l1.13 1.9a2 2 0 0 0 2.5.8zm2.82.97a4 4 0 0 1 3.12 0l2.04.87a4 4 0 0 0 4.99-1.62l1.14-1.9a4 4 0 0 1 2.53-1.84l2.15-.5a4 4 0 0 0 3.09-4.24l-.2-2.2a4 4 0 0 1 .97-2.98l1.45-1.67a4 4 0 0 0 0-5.24l-1.45-1.67a4 4 0 0 1-.97-2.97l.2-2.2a4 4 0 0 0-3.09-4.25l-2.15-.5a4 4 0 0 1-2.53-1.84l-1.14-1.9a4 4 0 0 0-5-1.62l-2.03.87a4 4 0 0 1-3.12 0l-2.04-.87a4 4 0 0 0-4.99 1.62l-1.14 1.9a4 4 0 0 1-2.53 1.84l-2.15.5a4 4 0 0 0-3.09 4.24l.2 2.2a4 4 0 0 1-.97 2.98l-1.45 1.67a4 4 0 0 0 0 5.24l1.45 1.67a4 4 0 0 1 .97 2.97l-.2 2.2a4 4 0 0 0 3.09 4.25l2.15.5a4 4 0 0 1 2.53 1.84l1.14 1.9a4 4 0 0 0 5 1.62l2.03-.87zM152 207a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm6 2a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-11 1a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-6 0a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm3-5a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-8 8a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm3 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm0 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4 7a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm5-2a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm5 4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4-6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm6-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-4-3a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4-3a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-5-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-24 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm16 5a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm7-5a7 7 0 1 1-14 0 7 7 0 0 1 14 0zm86-29a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm19 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-14 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-25 1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm5 4a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm9 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm15 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm12-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-11-14a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-19 0a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm6 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-25 15c0-.47.01-.94.03-1.4a5 5 0 0 1-1.7-8 3.99 3.99 0 0 1 1.88-5.18 5 5 0 0 1 3.4-6.22 3 3 0 0 1 1.46-1.05 5 5 0 0 1 7.76-3.27A30.86 30.86 0 0 1 246 184c6.79 0 13.06 2.18 18.17 5.88a5 5 0 0 1 7.76 3.27 3 3 0 0 1 1.47 1.05 5 5 0 0 1 3.4 6.22 4 4 0 0 1 1.87 5.18 4.98 4.98 0 0 1-1.7 8c.02.46.03.93.03 1.4v1h-62v-1zm.83-7.17a30.9 30.9 0 0 0-.62 3.57 3 3 0 0 1-.61-4.2c.37.28.78.49 1.23.63zm1.49-4.61c-.36.87-.68 1.76-.96 2.68a2 2 0 0 1-.21-3.71c.33.4.73.75 1.17 1.03zm2.32-4.54c-.54.86-1.03 1.76-1.49 2.68a3 3 0 0 1-.07-4.67 3 3 0 0 0 1.56 1.99zm1.14-1.7c.35-.5.72-.98 1.1-1.46a1 1 0 1 0-1.1 1.45zm5.34-5.77c-1.03.86-2 1.79-2.9 2.77a3 3 0 0 0-1.11-.77 3 3 0 0 1 4-2zm42.66 2.77c-.9-.98-1.87-1.9-2.9-2.77a3 3 0 0 1 4.01 2 3 3 0 0 0-1.1.77zm1.34 1.54c.38.48.75.96 1.1 1.45a1 1 0 1 0-1.1-1.45zm3.73 5.84c-.46-.92-.95-1.82-1.5-2.68a3 3 0 0 0 1.57-1.99 3 3 0 0 1-.07 4.67zm1.8 4.53c-.29-.9-.6-1.8-.97-2.67.44-.28.84-.63 1.17-1.03a2 2 0 0 1-.2 3.7zm1.14 5.51c-.14-1.21-.35-2.4-.62-3.57.45-.14.86-.35 1.23-.63a2.99 2.99 0 0 1-.6 4.2zM275 214a29 29 0 0 0-57.97 0h57.96zM72.33 198.12c-.21-.32-.34-.7-.34-1.12v-12h-2v12a4.01 4.01 0 0 0 7.09 2.54c.57-.69.91-1.57.91-2.54v-12h-2v12a1.99 1.99 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-1.66-.88zM75 176c.38 0 .74-.04 1.1-.12a4 4 0 0 0 6.19 2.4A13.94 13.94 0 0 1 84 185v24a6 6 0 0 1-6 6h-3v9a5 5 0 1 1-10 0v-9h-3a6 6 0 0 1-6-6v-24a14 14 0 0 1 14-14 5 5 0 0 0 5 5zm-17 15v12a1.99 1.99 0 0 0 1.22 1.84 2 2 0 0 0 2.44-.72c.21-.32.34-.7.34-1.12v-12h2v12a3.98 3.98 0 0 1-5.35 3.77 3.98 3.98 0 0 1-.65-.3V209a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h16a4 4 0 0 0 4-4v-24c.01-1.53-.23-2.88-.72-4.17-.43.1-.87.16-1.28.17a6 6 0 0 1-5.2-3 7 7 0 0 1-6.47-4.88A12 12 0 0 0 58 185v6zm9 24v9a3 3 0 1 0 6 0v-9h-6z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M-17 191a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm19 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-14 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-25 1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm5 4a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm9 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm15 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm12-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H4zm-11-14a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-19 0a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm6 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-25 15c0-.47.01-.94.03-1.4a5 5 0 0 1-1.7-8 3.99 3.99 0 0 1 1.88-5.18 5 5 0 0 1 3.4-6.22 3 3 0 0 1 1.46-1.05 5 5 0 0 1 7.76-3.27A30.86 30.86 0 0 1-14 184c6.79 0 13.06 2.18 18.17 5.88a5 5 0 0 1 7.76 3.27 3 3 0 0 1 1.47 1.05 5 5 0 0 1 3.4 6.22 4 4 0 0 1 1.87 5.18 4.98 4.98 0 0 1-1.7 8c.02.46.03.93.03 1.4v1h-62v-1zm.83-7.17a30.9 30.9 0 0 0-.62 3.57 3 3 0 0 1-.61-4.2c.37.28.78.49 1.23.63zm1.49-4.61c-.36.87-.68 1.76-.96 2.68a2 2 0 0 1-.21-3.71c.33.4.73.75 1.17 1.03zm2.32-4.54c-.54.86-1.03 1.76-1.49 2.68a3 3 0 0 1-.07-4.67 3 3 0 0 0 1.56 1.99zm1.14-1.7c.35-.5.72-.98 1.1-1.46a1 1 0 1 0-1.1 1.45zm5.34-5.77c-1.03.86-2 1.79-2.9 2.77a3 3 0 0 0-1.11-.77 3 3 0 0 1 4-2zm42.66 2.77c-.9-.98-1.87-1.9-2.9-2.77a3 3 0 0 1 4.01 2 3 3 0 0 0-1.1.77zm1.34 1.54c.38.48.75.96 1.1 1.45a1 1 0 1 0-1.1-1.45zm3.73 5.84c-.46-.92-.95-1.82-1.5-2.68a3 3 0 0 0 1.57-1.99 3 3 0 0 1-.07 4.67zm1.8 4.53c-.29-.9-.6-1.8-.97-2.67.44-.28.84-.63 1.17-1.03a2 2 0 0 1-.2 3.7zm1.14 5.51c-.14-1.21-.35-2.4-.62-3.57.45-.14.86-.35 1.23-.63a2.99 2.99 0 0 1-.6 4.2zM15 214a29 29 0 0 0-57.97 0h57.96z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        /*background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(indigo, violet);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(indigo, violet);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(indigo, violet);
    background: linear-gradient(indigo, violet);
    background-attachment: scroll;*/
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes blinkertext {
        from {
            opacity: 1.0;
        }
        to {
            opacity: 0.0;
        }
    }

    .blinktext {
        margin-top: 20px;
        -webkit-animation-name: blinkertext;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    }

    h4 {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    }

    p {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    }

    div {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    }



    .wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .relative {

        position: relative;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;

    }

    .centered {
        /*position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);*/
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    @keyframes blink {
        /**
    * At the start of the animation the dot
    * has an opacity of .2
    */
        0% {
            opacity: .2;
        }
        /**
    * At 20% the dot is fully visible and
    * then fades out slowly
    */
        20% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        /**
    * Until it reaches an opacity of .2 and
    * the animation can start again
    */
        100% {
            opacity: .2;
        }
    }

    .loading span {
        /**
    * Use the blink animation, which is defined above
    */
        animation-name: blink;
        /**
    * The animation should take 1.4 seconds
    */
        animation-duration: 1.4s;
        /**
    * It will repeat itself forever
    */
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        /**
    * This makes sure that the starting style (opacity: .2)
    * of the animation is applied before the animation starts.
    * Otherwise we would see a short flash or would have
    * to set the default styling of the dots to the same
    * as the animation. Same applies for the ending styles.
    */
        animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

    .loading span:nth-child(2) {
        /**
    * Starts the animation of the third dot
    * with a delay of .2s, otherwise all dots
    * would animate at the same time
    */
        animation-delay: .2s;
    }

    .loading span:nth-child(3) {
        /**
    * Starts the animation of the third dot
    * with a delay of .4s, otherwise all dots
    * would animate at the same time
    */
        animation-delay: .4s;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
        /*Debug which query gets fired by uncommenting this
    body::before {
        content: "media query (320+) fired";
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }*/
        h4 {
            font-size: 11px
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 9px
        }

        .material-icons {
            font-size: 11px
        }

        #disclaimer .material-icons {
            font-size: 9px;
            display: inline-flex;
            vertical-align: middle;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #turnDisclaimerPartySize {
            font-size: 9px
        }

        #positionWrapper {
            font-size: 11px
        }

        #timeWrapper {
            font-size: 11px
        }

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
        /*body::before {
        content: "media query (480+) fired";
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }*/
        h4 {
            font-size: 13px
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 11px
        }

        .material-icons {
            font-size: 13px
        }

        #disclaimer .material-icons {
            font-size: 11px;
            display: inline-flex;
            vertical-align: middle;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #turnDisclaimerPartySize {
            font-size: 11px
        }

        #positionWrapper {
            font-size: 13px
        }

        #timeWrapper {
            font-size: 13px
        }

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        /*body::before {
        content: "media query (768+) fired";
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }*/
        h4 {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 13px
        }

        .material-icons {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        #disclaimer .material-icons {
            font-size: 13px;
            display: inline-flex;
            vertical-align: middle;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #turnDisclaimerPartySize {
            font-size: 13px
        }

        #positionWrapper {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        #timeWrapper {
            font-size: 15px
        }

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        /*body::before {
        content: "media query (992+) fired";
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }*/
        h4 {
            font-size: 17px
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        .material-icons {
            font-size: 17px
        }

        #disclaimer .material-icons {
            font-size: 15px;
            display: inline-flex;
            vertical-align: middle;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #turnDisclaimerPartySize {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        #positionWrapper {
            font-size: 17px
        }

        #timeWrapper {
            font-size: 17px
        }

    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        /*body::before {
        content: "media query (1200+) fired";
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 99;
    }*/
        h4 {
            font-size: 19px
        }

        h6 {
            font-size: 17px
        }

        .material-icons {
            font-size: 19px
        }

        #disclaimer .material-icons {
            font-size: 17px;
            display: inline-flex;
            vertical-align: middle;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #turnDisclaimerPartySize {
            font-size: 17px
        }

        #positionWrapper {
            font-size: 19px
        }

        #timeWrapper {
            font-size: 19px
        }

    }
</style>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase

    function addZeroToHourOrMinute(hourOrMinuteValue) {

        return (hourOrMinuteValue < 10 ? '0' + hourOrMinuteValue : '' + hourOrMinuteValue);

    }

    function addAmPmNotation(hour) {

        return (hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");

    }

    function initialiseFirebaseAndAttachListener() {

        //Code which writes data to timtTillTurn and positionInList spans
        //Long and unnecessary for the cosmetic changes

    }

</script>
<title>Foodini Waitlist View</title>
</head>
<body onload="initialiseFirebaseAndAttachListener()">

<div class="container-fluid" id="mainbody">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="centered" align="center">

            <!-- Image logo text was created in Pacifico font -->
            <img src="/images/foodini_text_logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Foodini">

            <div align="center">
                <h4>YOUR CURRENT POSITION IS:</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="positionWrapper" align="center" class="valign-center">
                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                <span id="positionInList" style="margin-left:5px;">
                    <h4>
                        <span class="loading">Loading
                            <span>.</span>
                            <span>.</span>
                            <span>.</span>
                    </h4>
                    </span>
            </div>

            <div id="timeDiv" align="center">
                <h4>YOUR TURN SHOULD COME BY:</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="timeWrapper" align="center" class="valign-center">
                <i class="material-icons">schedule</i>
                <span id="timeTillTurn" style="margin-left:5px;">
                    <h4>
                        <span class="loading">Loading
                            <span>.</span>
                            <span>.</span>
                            <span>.</span>
                    </h4>
                    </span>
            </div>

            <div id="disclaimer" align="center" hidden>
                <h6>
                    <i class="material-icons">info_outline</i> The restaurant may overlook your turn for an empty table of size
                    <span id="turnDisclaimerPartySize">
                    </span> or more.</h6>
            </div>

            <div align="center" class="blinktext" class="h4">
                <h6>This page refreshes on it's own</h6>
            </div>

            <div id="applink" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; max-width: 300px auto 16px; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 3px;"
                align="center">
                <!-- DO NOT UNCOMMENT THIS P TAG <p>Install our app now</p> -->
                <!-- ADD THE HREF BACK WHEN THE LINK SHOULD BE ACTIVE href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foodini.waitlist.katana" -->
                <a>Coming-Soon</a>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <--This is the only new part in the original page-->
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
                        <div class="card card-block">Card</div>
                        <div class="card card-block">Card</div>
                        <div class="card card-block">Card</div>
                        <div class="card card-block">Card</div>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Now the cards do appear below the wrapper div, they get clipped on the left side completely. And there's no way to scroll to the clipped part.

Also if i try putting the div of the cards outisde the wrapper div, It gets randomly shown in the top part of the screen above the rest of the content. Can some one guide me as to how i should position the card list which can also increase in size below the current elements (the page excluding the card div) while not clipping it.

[Link to the changed page to view](https://fir-hosting-staging.firebaseapp.com/waitlistview/Ahmedabad/1/U1)

You can view it on a desktop and it will look fine, check it on a mobile and you will see it clipped

Comment: Are you able to include the associated HTML?

Comment: This is the complete file... this is all the html there is...

Comment: My apologies I only saw the CSS

Comment: No problem :) Glad you are helping, this is out of my scope of knowledge... can deal with any ui issue in android sdk but css, absolutely basic knowledge of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card list are cropped because of `flex-wrap: nowrap` property, [you can read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap). 
You need to use `flex-wrap: wrap` instead.

In your example you need to change `flex-nowrap` class from your `d-flex` element (cards parent) to `flex-wrap` class.

Update. Also I recommend to you this list of actions:

- Remove `position: absolute;` `left: 50%;` `top: 50%;` from `.wrapper` element.
- Remove `left: -50%;` `-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);` `-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);` `-moz-transform: translateY(-50%, -50%) transform: translateY(-50%);` from `.centered` element.
- Add `justify-content: center;` to `.d-flex` and `#offers` elements.

Comment: ok now the entire page is clipped and just the cards are visible... see the link, you will see the live results of all the changes i make there :'D

Comment: actually looks pretty decent on chrome, however on mozilla looks screwed up and to the left of the screen and my background svg looks clipped. Also there is no spacing between vertical cards, again, all of this is visible, you can check on your device if you like :)

Comment: mozilla mobile** looks amazing on chrome :)

Comment: never mind, it was a studpid cache issue, Looks good on mozilla too :) just need to add some spacing between cards

Comment: To add some spacing between cards add `margin-bottom: 10px;` property to `.card-block` element.

Comment: aha :) Amazing alex, you are a life saver sir :)